# Java passing map to Methods (Android)

Tags: java, android

How to I change this...

```
((PlateDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.content_pane))
            .setText(DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(id).content);
```

and this...

```
public void setText(String text) {
    ((TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.plate_detail)).setText(text);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Action Bar");
}
```

So that I can access DummyContent.ITEM.id, DummyContent.ITEM.desc, DummyContent.ITEM.content (etc etc) from setText() ?

Am a total noob, thanks!

Edit: DummyContent is set and defined from the DummyContent.java inside the Android SDK except fields have been added to each item of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
((PlateDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
        R.id.content_pane))
        .setText(DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(id));


public void setText(DummyContent dummy) {
    ((TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.plate_detail)).setText(dummy.content);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Action Bar");
}
```

Comment: If you find my answer correct, please accept the answer if someone else encounters the same problem, so he/she can use the same approach.